# Define variable in model method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting `keywords` array from html form with different keywords. I need to put them to the string with value like this `keyword1,keyword2,keyword3`.

The problem is with `keywords_line` string. I see it has value inside of .each cycle but it has not out of it. How to set `keywords_line` to work correctly?

```
  # models/item.rb
  before_save :create_slug_and_keywords

  def create_slug_and_keywords

    if defined? self.keywords
      self.keywords.each do |k|
        if defined? keywords_line
          keywords_line = keywords_line + ',' + k
        else 
          keywords_line = k
        end 
      end

      if defined? keywords_line # keywords_line is not defined here
        keywords = keywords_line
      else 
        keywords = nil
      end
    end
```

Comment: why don't you use join (from Array class) ? If keywords is a Array, then self.keywords.join(',')

Comment: thanks, it works! Can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If keywords is a Array, then self.keywords.join(',')

And a link to the doc.

http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Array.html#method-i-join